# Getting error while creating xlsx file

Tags: java, excel

i am getting error while creating xlsx file.can any one help me.

```
while(fromData.hasNext()){
    fromMessage =  fromData.next();
    messageRow2 = XSSFCellUtil.getRow(messageRowNum++, sheet1);
    XSSFCell errorCell2 = messageRow2.createCell(2);
    errorCell2.setCellValue(fromMessage);
    errorCell2.setCellStyle(styles.get("string"));
    errorCell2.setCellStyle(styles.get("wrap"));
    if(!(fromData.hasNext())){
        messageRowNum =tempMessageRowNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Full exception stack trace would be helpful, if any.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot find any reference to XSSFCellUtil. My advice is to use SS model since it supports both XSSF and HSSF and in order to get the row just retrieve it from the sheet by calling getRow(int rownum).

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html here are some examples

Comment: For this to be so, the comment box below the question is sufficient. If you're not able to leave comments because of lacking of reputation, then leave it to whoever can, quite frankly.

Comment: Hi..actually my eclipse itself throwing error..actually it was wrking fine with HSSFWorkbook..i just tried with XSSFWorkbook in my code.. i just importerd HSSFCellUtil from poi jar.now i am trying with XSSFCellUtil..but my eclipse not allowing me to do this means its throwing error.wt should i do...help me..

Comment: I provided my answer to his question, I am not commenting on something. If he uses SS as in the examples(which also makes it more generic) he will not have problems. If he chooses not to, he can still take a look at the examples and modify to his needs. There is a difference between answering a question and commenting on something already said...